# Клавиатура перекрывает всё, что находится под используемым EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

При нажатии на EditText "Добавить задачу" у меня расширяется пространство под ним с несколькими элементами. Я хочу, чтобы клавиатура не закрывала эти элементы и они продвигались вверх вместе с верхним EditText "Добавить задачу". Я пробовал добавить в manifest разные windowSoftInputMode, но это не помогает. Сейчас я использую клавишу Enter, чтобы перейти на нижний EditText.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В манифесте в вашу activity (это важно, именно в activity) добавьте: windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize".
Для примера я сделала простенький макет с ConstraintLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/edt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fr" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/purple_500"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


В коде:

    et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
              if (b)  fr.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Готово, все работает!

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!